# How I can get executed functions log in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, selenium, logging

I am using C#, Selenium 3.0.1.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);
chromeOptions.PerformanceLoggingPreferences = new ChromePerformanceLoggingPreferences()
                {
                    IsCollectingTimelineEvents = true,
                    IsCollectingPageEvents = true
                };

chromeOptions.PerformanceLoggingPreferences.AddTracingCategory("v8,v8.runtime,v8.runtime_stats,browser");

Browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I've used many tracing categories here, but can't find category where executed functions was logged. Is it possible to get logs of javascript programs executions (list of executed functions)? If possible how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium offers different [log types](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/LogType.cs): for `Client`, `Driver`, `Browser`, `Server` and `Profiler`.
Not sure what you mean exactly by

> get logs of javascript programs executions

but I'm thinking that you may want the browser logs that will contain the information about what happens in the browser (e.g. CSS not being able to execute because Firefox browser cannot interpret it, etc).
You may do it like so:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs;
var browserLogs = logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
```

You may want to encase the last line in a `try-catch` statement, because not all log types are available for all drivers. This assumes that you're executing your tests on multiple browsers and you want to get multiple types of logs.

Comment: I need the list of executed functions like a Timeline in devtools of chrome.

Comment: I see in the logs of driver how it ignores Client, Server and Profiler logs because of they are unrecognized.

Comment: As I said, that depends on the driver used. If i'm not mistaken, for Firefox, all of them are applicable. For the rest of the drivers, it depends whether they were / could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on what functions do you want, but basically their categories are `devtools.timeline`, `disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline` and `blink.user_timing`.

BTW, I guess you want to know categories of default timeline of Chrome DevTools, so here it is:

`__metadata,benchmark,devtools.timeline,rail,toplevel,disabled-by-default-v8.cpu_profiler,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,blink.user_timing,v8.execute,disabled-by-default-devtools.screenshot`

It is exactly the list of categories used in Performance tab of Chrome DevTools now.

Hope this help.